# Full deserialiazion of recursion property with Jackson JSON and Hibernate

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, recursion, jackson

I have 2 tables that have a N-N relationship. I'm using SpringBoot 2.3.9 with Hibernate

I managed to map them uni-directionally because of the way I query the objects.

ObjectB has a column that refers to himself and the recursion de-serialization via jackson is done only to the first occurence.

These are the mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_OBJECT_A")
public class ObjectA {

    // mapping N-N
    @JoinTable(name = "OBJECTA_X_OBJECTB",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
    )
    private Set<ObjectB> setObjectB = new HashSet<ObjectB>();

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_OBJECT_B")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
// false - because I need the full object
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = false)
public class ObjectB {

    // recursion
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_RECURSION_ID")
    private ObjectB objectBRecursion;

}
```

**findAll by JPA** json response:

```
[
  {
    "version": "2023-05-09T16:39:47.082+00:00",
    "id": 1619,
    "code": "TRSU",
    "setObjectB": [
      {
        "id": 31,
        "version": "2018-07-18T08:12:14.000+00:00",
        "code": "AMO"
      },
      {
        "id": 100,
        "version": "2023-04-18T10:00:45.786+00:00",
        "code": "SMO"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "version": "2023-05-09T16:33:25.404+00:00",
    "id": 1520,
    "codice": "SD",
    "setObjectB": [
      100
    ]
  },
  {
    "version": "2023-05-09T16:40:48.313+00:00",
    "id": 1620,
    "code": "TRSE",
    "setObjectB": [
      31,
      100
    ]
  },
  {
    "version": "2022-09-26T08:00:04.127+00:00",
    "id": 1019,
    "code": "test",
    "setObjectB": [
      31
    ]
  },
  {
    "version": "2023-04-18T09:50:27.744+00:00",
    "id": 1519,
    "code": "DI",
    "setObjectB": [
      31
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see, only the **first occurence** of **setObjectB** property is fully deserialized.

I need all of them.

[JsonIdentityInfo](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html)

Quoting the documentation,

> In practice this is done by serializing the first instance as full
> object and object identity, and other references to the object as
> reference values.

Is there a way to get the full pojo of each entries?

Comment: Hibernate manipulates the bytecode so that access to lazy-loaded fields are replaced with the code actually able to load the object from the database. Jackson uses reflection to access fields, so it cannot do that.

Comment: I'm looking for something to force Jackson do not fully serialized the first instance, but all of them doing the first depth level of recursion

Comment: Yeah, well that's another problem